# layered navigation not working with custom filters magento 2.4

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, magento2.4.1

layered navigation is not working with custom Collection filters in Magento 2.4
File Name - Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Category\CollectionFilter;

```php
$collection->addAttributeToSelect($this->catalogConfig->getProductAttributes())
        ->addMinimalPrice()
        ->addFinalPrice()
        ->addTaxPercents()
        ->addUrlRewrite($category->getId())
        ->setVisibility($this->productVisibility->getVisibleInCatalogIds());
        
$collection->getSelect()
            ->join(
                ['marketplace_assignproduct_items'],
                'e.entity_id= marketplace_assignproduct_items.assign_product_id',
                ['marketplace_assignproduct_items.seller_id']
            );
```

With help of this, I am able to display products properly in Category Page but layered navigation and Pagination not working properly.
Note - this issue with Magento 2.4

Comment: Are you using a third party layered navigation module?

Comment: Yes, @paj we are using Mirasvit layered navigation but still, the issue is there.

Comment: Any suggestion on this ?